# method header for user-defined array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
public class studentDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("How many students are there?: ");
        int numberOfstuds = scan.nextInt();

        int[] nOEarray = new int[numberOfstuds];

        System.out.println("\nEnter names of students up to the entered amount (" + numberOfstuds + "):");

        String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfstuds];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfstuds; i++) {
            namesArray[i] = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
    }
}
```

That is part of my code for letting user input array size, however I am tasked with using the header below just for a method to get the size of the array, but I have tried inserting it and keep getting different error messages such as needs body(if I put semi-colon) or "requires ';'" if I don't and when I put curly braces around the section where it gets  the array size it returns errors :Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    - Syntax error on token "create", AnnotationName expected after 
     this token

```
public static Student[] create()
```

Here is the Student class

```
public class Student {
    //private data members
    private String name;
    private long idNUmber;

    //constructor
    public Student(){
      name="Unassigned";
      idNUmber=0;
    }
    //overloaded constructor
    public Student(String x, long y) {
        name=x;
        idNUmber=y;
    }
    //getters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public long getIdNUmber() {
        return idNUmber;    
    }
    //setters
    public void setName(String n) {
        name=n;
    }
    public void setIdNUmber(long i) {
        idNUmber=i;
    }
    //override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: "+getName()+"\nID number: "+getIdNUmber();
    }
```

Comment: do you want to move the array initialisation in a separate method? It's unclear what you're asking because the snippet looks viable

Comment: yes to the method public static student[] create()

Comment: Did you create the class `Student`?

Comment: @Jade do you have the `Student` class to create a `Student[]` array?

Comment: @Jade we can't see it, add it to the snippet

Comment: @AndrewTobilko done

Comment: @Jade how precisely is the method `create` defined?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko as "method which asks the user for the size they wish the array to be and then creates an
array of type Student of the specified size"

Comment: @Jade how you did you define it? how did you write the method signature? what's in the method body?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That's my question.  I explained what I attempted to do in the question